# Jquery dataTable hide searchBox but show entries downdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to hide the search textbox of datatable and use my own custom textbox as I add icon to it.

Now, if I hide the search box using below code, it hides the show entries dropdown as well.

Any way to hide only the searchbox and remain the show entry drop down or using a custom drop down as replacement?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#example').DataTable(

        {
            "bFilter": false,
            searching: true,
            dom: "t",//show only table and hide the entry dropdown and searchbox
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "info": false

        });
    $('#searchText').keyup(function () {
        oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
    })
});
```

**Updated Code from  tomloprod**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#example').DataTable(

        {
            "bFilter": false,
            searching: true,
            "sDom": "l"//show only table and entry dropdown and searchbox


        });
    $('#searchText').keyup(function () {
        oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
    })
```

});

Comment: yes .first one works and is awesome. But how do i move it on top instead of bottom so corner.

Comment: Move what, the dropdown? Move the `l` option to the beginning of `sDom`

Comment: worked like a charm.i love you. anyway i updated the code for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this `sDom`:

```
"sDom": "rt<'fluid-row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>><'fluid-row'<'col-md-12 col-sm-12'<'pull-right'l>>>"
```

If you are not using bootstrap, you can remove this grid and use directly:

```
"sDom": "rtipl"
```

You can see how this works here: http://jsfiddle.net/za3jogqm/

---

You should read [DataTables documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) to take full advantage of this functionality.

> [...]
>
> The following options are allowed:
>
> **l** - Length changing
>   **f - Filtering input**
>   **t** - The table!
>   **i** - Information
>   **p** - Pagination
>   **r** - pRocessing
>
> [...]